# python multi-processing zombie processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zombie-process

I have a simple implementation of python's multi-processing module

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
jobs = []

while True:
    for i in range(40):
        # fetch one by one from redis queue
        #item = item from redis queue
        p = Process(name='worker '+str(i), target=worker, args=(item,))

        # if p is not running, start p
        if not p.is_alive():
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
        jobs.remove(j)


def worker(url_data):
    """worker function"""
    print url_data['link']
```

What I expect this code to do:

1. run in infinite loop, keep waiting for Redis queue.
2. if Redis queue not empty, fetch item.
3. create 40 multiprocess.Process, not more not less
4. if a process has finished processing, start new process, so that ~40 process are running at all time.

I read that, to avoid zombie process that should be bound(join) to the parent, that's what I expected to achieve in the second loop. But the issue is that on launching it spawns 40 processes, **workers finish processing and enter zombie state, until all currently spawned processes haven't finished**,
then in next iteration of "while True", the same pattern continues.

So my **question is**: 
How can I avoid zombie processes. and spawn new process as soon as 1 in 40 has finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a task like the one you described is usually better to use a different approach using `Pool`.

You can have the main process fetching data and the workers deal with it.

Following an example of `Pool` from [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

```
def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10])    # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
    print pool.map(f, range(10))          # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

I also suggest to use `imap` instead of `map` as it seems your task can be asynch.

Roughly your code will be:

```
p = Pool(40)

while True:
  items = items from redis queue
  p.imap_unordered(worker, items) #unordered version is faster


def worker(url_data):
  """worker function"""
  print url_data['link']
```

Comment: works perfectly, memory usages are a bit higher than Process though, i'm quite new to python, are you sure i should use pool instead of process

Comment: Of course it depends on your specific task. As a general rule, you're offloading work to a pool of workers. You don't need to communicate with workers directly during their work. Pools were made for this type of scenarios. :)